# Convert Key/Value String back to ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, string, hashmap, key-value, concurrenthashmap

I have a hangman game that sends a hashmap to each client as a string.

The HashMap stores each ID's: Guessed Letters,Decrypted Word,Score,if they have completed the game.

I send the hashmap as a string and it is returned to the client like this:

```
{"101"=["___DE________N___RS_U_____", "RED SUN", "1", "true"], "102"=["___DE________N___RS_U_____", "RED SUN", "5", "true"]}
```

My Question is how can I take this key value pair string back to a hashmap like: `ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>` ?

Comment: Serialization. Your `String` is already valid JSON. I like the Jackson JSON API

Comment: @j.seashell That's not JSON.

Comment: If you use unique delimiter between entries, you can  split it to entries using that delimiter. (Also clean the string of its `[]{}` characters). This is not going to be nice. Can you format the string as `XML` ?

Comment: @shmosel oh you're right, those are equal signs not colons, didn't look closely enough